# Cannot get documents or docs with cloud firestore : ^2.1.0 flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety, flutter2.0

I've just upgraded to `cloud firestore: ^2.1.0` and I have an error on `snapshots.data?.documents` or `snapshots.data?.docs` with message *The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.* in the above code :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Courses').snapshots(),
      builder: (context1, snapshot) {
        //just add this line
        if (snapshot.data == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data?.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context2, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => DetailCourseScreen(
                      snapshot.data?.documents[index]['title'],
                      snapshot.data?.documents[index]['storage'],
                      index),
                ),
              ),
              child: _buildCourseList(
                  context2, snapshot.data?.documents[index], index),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

And here is my `pubspec.yaml` :

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.12.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:

  cloud_firestore: ^2.1.0
  firebase_core: ^1.1.1
  firebase_storage: ^8.0.6
  firebase_image: ^1.0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your confusion. Accessing cloud firestore's data has gotten kind of weird since the update on cloud_firestore 2.0.0. You can access your data with the following code:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Courses')
          .withConverter<Map<String, dynamic>>(
            fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => snapshot.data() ?? Map<String, dynamic>(),
            toFirestore: (model, _) => Map<String, dynamic>.from(model as Map),
          )
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context2, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => DetailCourseScreen(
                      snapshot.data?.docs[index].data()['title'],
                      snapshot.data?.docs[index].data()['storage'],
                      index),
                ),
              ),
              child: _buildCourseList(context2, snapshot.data?.docs[index].data(), index),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

You can read more about this update here: https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/changelog#200

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would like to upvote your answer but SO do not take in count. For more precision and make sure anyone can simply copy paste, I would like to edit your answer based on my IDE's errors (just need null check :) ) : `.withConverter<Map<String, dynamic>>(
            fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => snapshot.data() **?? Map<String, dynamic>()**,
            toFirestore: (model, _) => Map<String, dynamic>.from(model as Map),
          )`

Comment: @Xsims Thanks for the edit! Amazing team work! I have approved the edit.